# Why is Logger crashing my Google Apps JSP?

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp

I'm running Google Apps locally via eclipse. I connect to `http://localhost:8888/` and sometimes Eclipse will throw an exception from this line 374 in AccessControlContext.class:

```
    throw new AccessControlException("access denied "+perm, perm);
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Thread [299085@qtp-12256262-2] (Suspended (exception AccessControlException))   

AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Permission) line: 374  
AccessController.checkPermission(Permission) line: 546  
DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager(SecurityManager).checkPermission(Permission) line: 532    
DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(Permission) line: 289 
DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager(SecurityManager).checkPackageAccess(String) line: 1512    
Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: 298    
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 247    
ResourceBundle$RBClassLoader.loadClass(String) line: 435    
ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(String, Locale, String, ClassLoader, boolean) line: 2289   
ResourceBundle.loadBundle(CacheKey, List<String>, Control, boolean) line: 1364  
ResourceBundle.findBundle(CacheKey, List<Locale>, List<String>, int, Control, ResourceBundle) line: 1328    
ResourceBundle.findBundle(CacheKey, List<Locale>, List<String>, int, Control, ResourceBundle) line: 1282    
ResourceBundle.findBundle(CacheKey, List<Locale>, List<String>, int, Control, ResourceBundle) line: 1282    
ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(String, Locale, ClassLoader, ResourceBundle$Control) line: 1224    
ResourceBundle.getBundle(String) line: 705  
Level.getLocalizedName() line: 223  
SimpleFormatter.format(LogRecord) line: 64  
ConsoleHandler(StreamHandler).publish(LogRecord) line: 179  
ConsoleHandler.publish(LogRecord) line: 88  
Logger.log(LogRecord) line: 478 
Logger.doLog(LogRecord) line: 500   
Logger.log(Level, String) line: 523 
Logger.warning(String) line: 1026
```

I'm calling just this:

```
    log.warning("string");
```

and log is initialized like so:

```
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyServletName.class.getName());
```

What is breaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this line instead. I normally use something similar to the following line when I write GAE code:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyServletName.class.getSimpleName());
```

So, use `getSimpleName()` instead of `getName()`. Read java.lang.Class javadoc on [getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()) and [getSimpleName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName()). The former probably appends an 'L' character to the end of the class type name, while the latter does not possess this (in your situation, undesirable) behaviour.

Also, consider using **Guice Injection** for the class's Logger object.